# Attach an email as an item attachment, which includes another attachment

Tags: angular, microsoft-graph-api

I have been developing an email client using Angular and Microsoft Graph. I am struggling to do an item attachment which has another attachment (let's say a single text file).

I have already went through the [Microsoft Graph documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20181003130445/https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/message_post_attachments) and the  "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46528376/send-new-message-that-includes-a-different-message-from-users-inbox-as-attachme/46954993#46954993"  question. Both the resources describe how to perform an item attachment operation.

In my case, I get an error when I try to attach an item that itself contains an attachment (i.e. a text file).

**Here is my approach:**

```js
onAttachToNewMail() {
if (this.selectedItems && this.selectedItems.length > 0) {
  const itemAttachments: ItemAttachment[] = this.selectedItems.map(value => {
    const item = <EventMessage>value.data;
    const attachment: ItemAttachment = {
      name: item.subject,
      item: value.data
    };
    attachment.item['@odata.type'] = item.meetingMessageType ? 'microsoft.graph.eventMessage' : 'microsoft.graph.message';
    return attachment;
  });
  this.attachToNewMail.emit(itemAttachments);
}
```

**The error message:**

> The property `attachments` does not exist on type `Microsoft.OutlookServices.Message`. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type or mark the type as open type.

How can I fix this problem? Please let me know a solution or workaround to achieve this.

Comment: Can you add the `POST`  you are submitting to Microsoft Graph (particularly of interest is the JSON)?